# How to get total number of entries with specific condition in data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, count

I have a data frame data here [data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KU8P2KHjCiEKOqPXarTxrCKjgGnIGHeW/view?usp=share_link). I want to know the genes that have a value satisfying a specific condition, such as greater than 0.15. I want to subset the data by finding all genes that have a value that satisfies this > 0.15 condition. I have tried this

```
moran_deviation_data_multiple_correction_1january_BH_conclusion_spatially_clustered_threshold_0.15 = data
moran_deviation_data_multiple_correction_1january_BH_conclusion_spatially_clustered_threshold_0.15 = as.data.frame(moran_deviation_data_multiple_correction_1january_BH_conclusion_spatially_clustered[1,])
moran_deviation_data_multiple_correction_1january_BH_conclusion_spatially_clustered_threshold_0.15 = moran_deviation_data_multiple_correction_1january_BH_conclusion_spatially_clustered_threshold_0.15[,colSums(moran_deviation_data_multiple_correction_1january_BH_conclusion_spatially_clustered_threshold_0.15[1,] <= 0.15) == 0]

moran_deviation_data_multiple_correction_1january_BH_conclusion_spatially_clustered_threshold_0.15
```

It will result this [image: pic 1] and this [image: pic 2] and for some reason it includes value that less than 0.15 so this is wrong output. How can I get it fixed? Or how can I get the result as expected?

Comment: I can't help but cringe at a variable name that, by itself, triggers auto-line-wrap logic.

Comment: `colSums(X[1,] <= 0.15)` (where `X` is your variable name) seems odd. `colSums` sums each column, and since you're passing it a single row, it is _identical_ to `X[1,] <= 0.15`. Further, your use of `== 0` is a little unnecessarily obscure, why not just `X[, X[1,] > 0.15]`?

Comment: But ... note that all of your columns are `<chr>`, so _nothing is numeric_. One can never assume that the sorting of variable-decimals numbers will be the same between `character` and `numeric` data. Compare `0.15 < 5.3e-3` and `"0.15" < "5.3e-3"`.

Comment: Since the _image_ of your data (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/)) shows `<chr>`, and your file parses _correctly_ (i.e., `<dbl>`) with both `read.csv` and `fread`, it seems like that either you messed up the column classes while reading in the file, or some interim step corrupted it from numbers to strings. In either case, the error happens in code we do not know. I suggest you go back and figure out at what point (including immediately post-import) your data is not numeric, and fix that point.

Answer (score 2):

Your values are `character`. You cannot make numeric-comparisons and assume it will match with strings. For example,

```r
0.15 < 5.3e-3
# [1] FALSE
"0.15" < "5.3e-3"
# [1] TRUE
```

Convert your data to `numeric` and then rerun your logic. Perhaps

```r
moran_deviation_data_multiple_correction_1january_BH_conclusion_spatially_clustered[] <-
  lapply(moran_deviation_data_multiple_correction_1january_BH_conclusion_spatially_clustered,
         type.convert, as.is = TRUE)
```

(The use of brackets in `...[] <- ...` is intentional, without the `[]` you'll get a `list` instead of retaining the class `data.frame`.)

Comment: Thanks. It helps actually and now my code is working.

Answer (score 0):

I did some renaming of variables but this should work.

```
library(data.table)

md_015 = as.data.frame(fread("moran_deviation_data_multiple_correction_1january_BH_conclusion_spatially_clustered.csv"))
md_015_index = which(md_015 > .15)

refined_df <- md_015[,md_015_index] 

refined_df
```

```
> refined_df
           V1   METTL7B       DBI       SLN     COX5B     ITM2C     PTGDS     GLUL
1 Moran.index 0.1682925 0.1586386 0.1913133 0.1541711 0.1533256 0.1910979 0.157243
```

Comment: I do not know why but it worked differently in my code when I tried this, I still got the same result as before. I will check

Comment: maybe you did not make it a dataframe right away when reading it in? It would throw an error here ```md_015[,md_015_index] ``` in that case.